# How to type a non-breaking hyphen (dash, "-" character) in scientific or technical documents

Tags: symbols, hyphenation

I am writing scientific or technical documents in LaTeX. Often I need to type a non-breaking space, for example when using equation references:

```
Equation~\eqref{eq:equation1example} shows blaa...
```

Is there a way of inserting non-breaking hyphens?

For example, this may be useful for technical terms such as `Runge-Kutta`, `non-linear`, `non-converging` or `Van-der-Pol Oscillator` which would not usually be split over lines.

Additionally, this may be desirable for citations and Author names, or publisher names.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you use the [amsmath](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/required/amslatex/math/) package, you could employ its `\nobreakdash` macro to insert a dash or en-dash after which no line break is allowed.

Three examples (all from the user guide of the `amsmath` package):

```
$p$\nobreakdash-adic
$n$\nobreakdash-dimensional
pages 1\nobreakdash--9
```

Basically, where you'd normally write `-` ("dash") in the input file, you would now write `\nobreakdash-`, and where you'd normally write `--` ("en-dash"), you would now write `\nobreakdash--`.

The joined-up expression `$n$\nobreakdash-dimensional` is quite long and might create bad line breaks. To keep this from happening, while still prohibiting a linebreak after `$n$-`, you could write

```
$n$\nobreakdash-\hspace{0pt}dimensional
```

That way, if need be, LaTeX can find a line break somewhere inside the "dimensional" substring. Presumably, you're OK with `$n$-dimen-` being at the end of one line and `sional` at start of the next line. If you have a lot of instances of "n-dimensional" in your document, it may make sense to set up a macro such as

```
\newcommand\ndim{$n$\nobreakdash-\hspace{0pt}dimensional}
```

in the preamble and to write `\ndim{}` everywhere in the body of the document.

Answer (score 20):

With the [`babel`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/babel) package loaded there is `\babelhyphen{nobreak}` available (alongside `\babelhyphen{soft}`, `\babelhyphen{hard}` and a few others). While it prohibits a break after the dash the following word may still be hyphenated:

```
$n$\babelhyphen{nobreak}dimensional
```

The language `ngerman` (maybe others, too) defines a shorthand for a non-breaking hyphen: `"~`. With `\addto\extrasenglish{\languageshorthands{ngerman}}` it (and the other `ngerman` shorthands) can be added to `english` for example. (It probably must be activated with `\useshorthands{"}`. Contrary to `\babelhyphen{nobreak}` `"~` does not allow the following word to be hyphenated.

```
% preamble
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
\addtoextrasenglish{\languageshorthands{ngerman}\useshorthands{"}}
...
% document
$n$"~dimensional
```

You can also define the shorthand yourself – either general

```
\defineshorthand{"~}{\babelhyphen{nobreak}}
\useshorthands{"}
```

or explicitly for one language (`english` as example):

```
\defineshorthand[english]{"~}{\babelhyphen{nobreak}}
\addto\extrasenglish{
  \languageshorthands{english}
  \useshorthands{"}
}
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}

\defineshorthand[english]{"~}{\babelhyphen{nobreak}}
\addto\extrasenglish{
  \languageshorthands{english}
  \useshorthands{"}
}

\begin{document}

% default:
\parbox{3em}{$n$-dimensional}

\bigskip
% \babelhyphen{nobreak}:
\parbox{3em}{$n$\babelhyphen{nobreak}dimensional}

\bigskip
% new `english' shorthand:
\parbox{3em}{$n$"~dimensional}

\bigskip\selectlanguage{ngerman}
% `ngerman' shorthand:
\parbox{3em}{$n$"~dimensional}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am open to criticism: if the downvoter kindly would tell me in which respect my answer is bad/wrong? I'll gladly edit/delete if I know why.

Comment: I, for one, upvoted your answer. :-) Absent some clear criticism, I tend to no longer worry too much about any downvotes. Quite a few of the downvotes I've received over time turned out to be entirely accidental, of the "fat-finger" variety -- where somebody meant to upvote but managed to downvote instead. Plus, the fat-finger problem has afflicted me too at times, i.e., I've accidentally downvoted other postings. (I correct those mistakes, though!)

Comment: @Mico i don't worry but I'm curious :)

Answer (score 5):

It is also possible to wrap part of text that should not be wrapped or only the dash in `\mbox{…}`:

```
\mbox{non-linear}
non\mbox{-}linear
```

Comment: Wrapping only part of the text will compromise the kerning in the word.  But also, wrapping any part of the string in braces will suppress all hyphenation within the string

Comment: this is the way, no additional packages necessary

Comment: @Sergiu - why does the fact that no additional packages are necessary that "this is the way"?

Comment: @Mico the fewer packages the better, as in my experiences when submitting papers to conferences or journals there is tons of resistance to using many packages, because imagine 100 papers accepted from different authors and each using their preferred packages, then putting the content together in one document can be a hassle with conflicting packages

Comment: @Sergiu - There are plenty of obscure and largely undebugged LaTeX packages out there. However, `babel` and `amsmath` -- the two packages whose used by the other two answers to this query -- are definitely *not* in that category; indeed, quite the opposite is the case. To use your rhetoric: Imagine 100 papers accepted from different authors; if the clear majority of these papers did *not* employ either `amsmath` or `babel` (or both), one would very much have to worry about the apparent lack of basic LaTeX competence of the set of authors.

Answer (score 0):

The package [`extdash`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/extdash) provides several options for typesetting hyphens and dashes, including disabling line-breaks after them by either:

1. adding an asterisk to the written-out command

```
something\Hyphdash* something
something\Endash* something
```

2. with the `shortcuts` option loaded, using equal signs instead of hyphens:

```
something\=/something
something\==/something
```

(examples from the package documentation)