# Prevent line-breaking inside acronym which contains a hyphen ("dash") character

Tags: line-breaking, hyphenation, acronyms

How can I prevent line-breaking of an acronym which contains a hyphen? I have the acronym "`AP-CMOS`" all over my document, and it's been broken in several places into "`AP-`" and "`CMOS`". The same occurs with the compound "`1\textsuperscript{st}-order`". I tried using `\hyphenation` without any luck. Thanks, Jorge.

Comment: `\mbox{AP-COMOS}`?

Comment: Thanks CarLaTex! This seems to solve the problem. Is this the usual way to achieve this? (wonder if \hyphenation can handle these cases at all!)

Comment: I leave the answer to some expert...

Comment: If you have loaded the `amsmath` package, you can also use `AP\nobreakdash-CMOS`. Please also take a look at [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/263883/164314) for your “1st-order” problem. I think the consensus is “if you write something repetitively, then perhaps create a macro for that”.