# Non-breaking hyphen in Plain TeX

Tags: line-breaking, hyphenation, plain-tex

I am asking the same question as this post:

[How to type a non-breaking hyphen (dash, "-" character) in scientific or technical documents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/263876/how-to-type-a-non-breaking-hyphen-dash-character-in-scientific-or-technic)

but I don't want to use any package (just to understand how it may be done in Plain TeX with just the primitives of the language).

```
\mbox{non-linear}
non\mbox{-}linear
```

will prevent hyphenation

What about:

```
non-\nobreak linear
```

I don't know how to check where the possible break points are in TeX.

Comment: `\mbox` is a LaTeX-only command. For PlainTeX, you probably want `\hbox`.

Answer (score 3):

your suggested use of `\nobreak` does not prevent a breeak as can be seen by

```
\vbox{\hsize=1pt
a
non-\nobreak linear
}

\bye
```

[image]

The first two suggestions with `\mbox` are not plain TeX, but if you use `\hbox` they would prevent a break.

```
\vbox{\hsize=1pt
a
\hbox{non-linear}
non\hbox{-}linear
}

\bye
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer, what about hyphenation?

Comment: @richardIII the hbox prevents hyphenation

Answer (score 3):

With `non-\nobreak linear` you don't inhibit a line break after the hyphen, unless you specify `\exhyphenpenalty=10000` and `\nobreak` is redundant.

```
\vbox{\hsize=0pt \parindent=0pt
  \hskip0pt non-\nobreak linear
}
\vbox{\hsize=0pt \parindent=0pt \exhyphenpenalty=10000
  \hskip0pt non-linear
}
\bye
```

[image]

On the other hand, setting `\exhyphenpenalty` to `10000` seems too drastic and you get no hyphenation in the rest of the word anyway.

```
\def\nbh{%
  \leavevmode % one never knows
  \hbox{-}% this won't allow a line break
  \nobreak % no line break here
  \hskip0pt % allow hyphenation on the rest of the word
}

\vbox{\hsize=0pt \parindent=0pt
  \hskip0pt
  non\nbh linear
}

\bye
```

[image]